# App Engine PHP - dev_appserver works but appspot does not

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gcloud

My project is a basic php website, with just a small bit of php for including header/footer.

**Project Structure**

1. `app.yaml` resides in root with a `/www` directory in root also
2. inside `/www` dir is all php files and an `/www/assets` directory
3. `/www/assets` contains all static files.

**Config Files**

app.yaml file is constructed as such:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  script: www/index.php

- url: /about.php
  script: www/about.php

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

Concerned this isn't quite correct.

Also do I need any other config files like php.ini? or app.yaml will be enough?

**Problem**

When I run the project locally using `dev_appserver.py .` it works perfect.

However when I deploy project using `gcloud app deploy` I get:

"*http error 404, this page can not be found*".

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not want to match the `www` itself in the `static_files`, because by default that means the `.php` files from that location will not be seen as application files.

You should configure just the `/www/assets` with `static_files` (last one, to not match the `static_files` url pattern) and keep the recommended `.php` handler from the google [example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#example):

```
- url: /
  script: www/index.php

# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: www/\1

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/assets/\1
  upload: www/assets/(.*)
```

Alternatively you *might* be able to just use the `application_readable` option (first row in the [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#handlers_element) table):

> **application_readable**
>
> Optional. Boolean. By default, files declared in static file handlers
>   are uploaded as static data and are only served to end users. They
>   cannot be read by an application. If this field is set to true, the
>   files are also uploaded as code data so your application can read
>   them. Both uploads are charged against your code and static data
>   storage [resource quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Code).

Like this:

```
- url: /
  script: www/index.php

- url: /about.php
  script: www/about.php

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
  application_readable: true
```

Personally I find the 1st approach cleaner.